# Trying to set my Android Xml Layout to work when scaled

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am trying to set my android XML up like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODvHf.png and my layout has to be very scaleable for all the different android screen sizes also it needs to work with all the different version of android. The screen will be locked in landscape view so you don't have to worry about portrait view. The first group (Regular hours and above numbers) need to expand and shrink together as well as the Overtime Hours. Also setting up the Full Report in the centered vertically like it is. Each set of number/text need to be in there own text view so i can style them individually. would love some help on this for some reason i cant wrap my mind around it lol. I am fairly new to Android XML. I have try'ed the different layouts Relative does not scale right with different screen sizes, and Grid Layout just gives me to much trouble because of all the different text views and the off set of the Full Report Link.
So looking forward to a solution. And thank you for any future help.(Here is were i am with my code right now.)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffe4e4e4"
>
<View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#ffa9a9a9"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:background="#ffd1d1d1"
    android:src="@drawable/top_bottom_border">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row_1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:text="40"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:text="hrs"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:text="30"

            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="min"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Regular"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="View Time Log"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:textColor="#ff0009ff"
            android:gravity="right"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row_2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:text="15"

            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hrs"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="17"

            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="min"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OverTime"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:gravity="right"/>


        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try using a LinearLayout, using match_parent, like so.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and then fill that out however you need.  This should create a scalable view with each item taking up a third of the screen.  You can adjust `android:layout_weight` as necessary.  I believe the total sum of the weights is arbitrary, but the higher the weight, the it will take `(weight) / (total_weight)` of the screen size.  Hope this helps!

Comment: The issue, I am having with both of your answer os that there are two lines of text and they have to stretch together both of yours would work if I was just doing one separate line. Here is, were my code is right now this may help you understand a little better.(I will add my code to the top)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend enclosing the three elements in a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"        
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button 2" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:text="Button 3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"         
        />   


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It works great for both portrait and landscape:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think this will work, it would work great for buttons but not for all the text views i am using and the different lines i have to deal with. Plz look at the above code i just added it my help you see were i am coming from.

Comment: You could enclose each text group in a View. And those views would replace the button in the layout. However your code is hardly readable, try adding some ids to your elements so it's easier to decode and you could also post a screenshot of your result.